# Environment-specific variables in Android

Tags: android

I have a very simple app that's basically a `WebView` pointing to a website, which is actually the real app.

Right now, if I want to test or deploy to the Play Store, I always have to go and change the URL the WebView is pointing to (change from the testing URL on my local machine vs the production URL, or vice-versa).

Is there any way to have some config files named like `settings-local.???` and `settings-production.???` which holds some environment-related variables which get placed in the code at build time? Preferably with a prompt asking me which environment I am building for, but I can manually do it if need be :)

Comment: if you use android studio you can the same constant with different values in different flavours